# Will List<Func<double, double>> cause memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory-management

I have a function that takes in a list of functors:

`public void RunFunc(List<Func<double, double>> functorList)`

The thing is that the `Func<double, double>` are assigned with methods from different objects. My concern now is that the garbage collector would always hold pointers to these methods, and always hold the memory for those objects because the GC doesn't know how to dispose them.

Am I right? Will `RunFunc` cause memory leak? If yes, what I should do to free the memory that are held by `List<Func<double, double>> functorList`?

Comment: Is `RunFunc` doing anything with the list other than just executing each function? Unless it stores a reference to the list or any of the functions, `RunFunc` itself won't cause any memory leaks.

Comment: @Rawling, it is just executing the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a list of delegates, and while this list exists it will hold a reference to every object that each delegate references.

If the `RunFunc` method stores this list as a member, than the objects will not be garbage collected as long as the list is stored. This is a good thing - otherwise it might later try calling a function on an object that has been destroyed.

As soon as the list stops being referenced it will no longer be preventing the objects from being garbage collected.

So, in answer to your question, `RunFunc` really isn't any different from any other CLR method, and the same garbage collection rules will apply as always.

Here's a simpler example:

```
Action myAction = null;
{
   var widget = new Widget();
   myAction = () => { widget.ScooblyWob() }; 
}
// the widget object has gone out of scope, but will stay in memory
// It is not a candidate for garbage collection, because 
// it is being referenced by the myAction function.

myAction(); 
// Even though I have no explicit references to the widget, 
// I just called a function on it!

myAction = null;
// Now the action has been dereferenced, 
// so the widget is a garbage collection candidate
```

Answer (score 4):

No, this will not cause a memory leak.

As soon as the `List<>` becomes unreachable it will be collected. The `Func<>` items are outgoinf references. Only incoming references can keep something alive.

Comment: why? Can you please explain. Thanks.

Comment: It can cause a memory leak if the `List<Func<...>>` is keeped somewhere.

Comment: @felix Everything can cause a leak by storing references. That's not really on the table here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman True, but i want to point out that he never said he is not keeping the reference, so it would cleaner if you point that out in your post.

Comment: @Felix that's not a leak that memory usage, a leak is unrecoverable memory usage (I.e. stuff you can't use because you don't have a ref for it and that the GC can't collect)